# Php Yii relations with junction table

Tags: php, yii, relational-database, junction-table

In one of my views in my project I need to display table that uses data from two tables, but one of them is juction table.

I have two tables **User** and **Skill**. Relation between these two is Many-to-Many so I created junction table **StudentSkills**.

This juction table doesn't only have *id_user* and *id_skill* as usually but also percentage value which is unique for given pair of ids - that's why it's in junction table even if you shouldn't put anything else there as a good practice.

In said table in a view I need to display rows containing *Name* from **Skill** table and *percentage* from **StudentSkills** junction table of a certion user.

This is my view:

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'skills-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->with('student_skills')->searchWithStudentId($id),
        'template' => '{items}{pager}',
        'cssFile'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl. '/themes/'. Yii::app()->theme->name.'/css/table.css',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'datagrid', 'style'=>'width:550px;'),
        'columns'=>array(
            array(
                'name'=>Yii::t('MainTrans', 'Name'),
                'value' => '$data->name',
                                        ),
            array(
                'name'=>'percentage',
                'header' => Yii::t('MainTrans', 'Success rate %'),
                'value' => '$data->student_skills->percentage',
                 ),
            ),
    ));

?>
```

And this is my search and relations in my Skill $model:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        //the first two relations were generated by gii
        'problems' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Problems', 'problem_skill(id_skill, id_problem)'),
        'users' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'User', 'student_skills(skill_id, student_id)'),

        //this is what tired to do
        'student_skills' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'StudentSkills', 'skill_id'),
    );
}

public function searchWithStudentId($studentId)
{
    // my custom search to find all records with certain user_id

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);

    $criteria->with = array('student_skills');
    $criteria->together = true;

    $criteria->compare('student_skills.student_id',$studentId);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>25,
            ),
            'sort'=>array(
                    'defaultOrder'=>array(
                            'title'=>CSort::SORT_ASC
                    )
            ),
    ));
}
```

When I'm trying to render page I get error: *Trying to get property of non-object*.

I know there is something wrong with my code and it's most probably something to do with relations but I cant find anything.

Can someone help with this problem without having to create new table?

Thanks

Comment: You have written `student_skills` in `'dataProvider'=>$model->with('student_skills')->searchWithStudentId($id),`and then in the `searchWithStudentId()` function, you again have `$criteria->with = array('student_skills');`

Comment: Try changing `'dataProvider'=>$model->with('student_skills')->searchWithStudentId($id),` to `'dataProvider'=>$model->searchWithStudentId($id),`

Comment: @KunalDethe - I tried your suggestion in second post but it didn't work. I don't really get what you wanted to say by your first comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `HAS_MANY` relation which means that every `Skill` model has more than **1** `StudentSkill`. You are getting an array of `student_skills`, so you need to do something with it. For example get first percentage in array

```
$data->student_skills[0]->percentage
```

or calculate average percentage for the given skill

```
array_sum($data->student_skills)/count($data->student_skills)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion worked, I used $data->student_skills[0]->percentage